# How to report on hours per period in Azure Devops?

Tags: time, azure-devops, tracking, hour, time-tracking

I can't work out how to report how many hours per week were recorded by each team member.

For example if a task is 20 hrs, and 10 hours was done last week, and 10 this week, how can I tell how meany hours were recorded against the task each week?

I saw some time tracker plugins, they are not what I'm talking about. They require that the user start and stop time tracking kind of like upwork.

The developers already enter completed hours as they progress the tasks. So if devops remember the dates of each entry then I should be able to query how many hours were added this week, or month, or whatever per user per task.

Here is an excerpt from a discussion we had about it:

> Meh, as far as Im concerned:
>
> 1. I make the tasks in notepad usually, so someone can add them to devops.
> 2. Someone adds them to develops.
> 3. The developers receive them in devops and record their status and times as they develop.
> 4. Devops doesnt seem to report on weekly times to us, so we ask the developers to write everything down in notepad or doc and pass us a
>    list or what they did with times.
> 5. We get the developers lists and use them to report to mgmt.
>
> SO
>
> What is the point of steps 2 and 3? May as well just pass the guys
> their task in plain test list as I make it in notepad, it will be
> easier for them to add their times and pass it back. For us devops is
> just extra unwanted work while ever we cant work out how to report on
> developer hours.

Comment: Time tracking of this type is usually a sign of extremely poor management. It is also unclear how your question relates to devops at all.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific product, like [tag:azure-devops]?

Comment: Yes, I added the azure-devops tag

Comment: @taleodor seriously? Did you really ask "how does tracking developer time in devops relate to devops"? And state that "keeping track of project and developer times scopes and budgets is poor mgmt"? Did you even read what you wrote? If you dont understand the question, dont know the answer, or dont have anything useful to contribute then why comment?

Comment: @taleodor there are many reasons why you might want to do this. E.g. I have a contractor working for me who is super productive, but senior management want to pull her funding. For them my word alone is not good enough. Evidencing her burn-down vs team average will probably be enough to persuade them to continue funding.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use several ways:

**Way 1. Use PowerBi reporting**.

1. Each developer updates work hours every day.
2. You can use Analytics view to get task history:

[image]

3. Add `Completed work` to this view.

[image]

4. [Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops). Then you can find revisions for each tasks and calculate hour difference

[image]

**Way 2. Customize your process template**.

1. Add to your process template new work item type (like `Time` or `Activity`). Add to these work items new field (like `Activity date`) or use existing field `Target Date`. Add to these work items the `Completed Work` field. [Add a custom work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-wit?view=azure-devops), [Add a custom field to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops).
2. You developers add a new `Time` work item as child work item to their task and update the `Completed Work` field. You can use work item queries to see time updates.

Comment: Thanks, that may kinda work, however the developers already record their time in the 'Completed' field, so it seems strange that they would need to also update a time field with the same info. Also, how would I report on the months previous to adding this extension? Azure devops is not dodgy brothers project mgmt system, its supposed to be the best paid devops system in the world. Im dumbfounded if it doesnt report recorded hours for a given period?

Comment: @ekerner You can use simple _Way 1. Use PowerBi reporting_ and get reports for any periods. But here your developers should update Completed Work every day. _Way 2. Customize your process template_ is more complex way. But here your developer may report to other days. Additionally on way 2, you can create custom job to sum completed work into parent task.

Comment: Thank for the info. Neither way is suitable, because if the developers need to make the extra action to record (duplicate) their time in a location other than the existing 'Completed' Field then there are loads of time trackers out there I can just use any of them.